# How to solve $\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{4}{5}=\sqrt{\sin(30^\circ)+\sin\frac{7\pi}{4}}$

Tags: trigonometry

I did it as: $$\Bigl(\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{4}{5}\Bigr)^2=\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\Biggr)^2.$$ But after, got big numbers $$225x^2-63-\sqrt{2}=0.$$ It would be very good, if someone showed the correct way of solving this. It must be solved in $\Bbb R.$

Comment: There is a ugly mixture of *degrees* and *radians*. If I may suggest, avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{4}{5}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}},$$
which is impossible because $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}<0$.

The answer is $\oslash$

Comment: why? it can't have a complex solution? It seems the case.

Comment: @Arnaldo Maybe do you mean to solve it in $\mathbb K$? I think to solve it in $\mathbb H$ or in $\mathbb O$ it's more interesting. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know any of those. But if you think about a more complete solution, maybe it cans help the OP. In my opinion, looking the equation, it looks like a complex solution is wanted, but it is just my opinion.

Comment: @Arnaldo I think it's obvious that we need to solve it in $\mathbb R$. We'll see what Tug'tekin will say.

Comment: If you say so...

Comment: @michaelrozenberg 

> I think it's obvious that we need to solve it in R.

You are right.

Comment: @Tug'tekin If so then give me V. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I meant, when you said "I think it's obvious that we need to solve it in $\Bbb R$" that was right, it must be solved in $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 3):

You have to solve for $x = \frac{2}{3}\left[\frac{4}{5}+\sqrt{1/2-1/\sqrt{2}} \right]$, the solution will be complex so $x = \frac{2}{3}\left[\frac{4}{5}\pm i\sqrt{-1/2+1/\sqrt{2}}\right]$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then you must conclude that the euquation does not have a solution. You will only get solutions if $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that $\;A^2=B^2\iff A=\pm B$, whether you're working in $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$ – actually this is valid in any field.

So you equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{3x}2-\frac45=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{2}}=\pm i\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}},$$
whence
$$x=\frac8{15}\pm\frac{i}{3}\sqrt{2\bigl(\sqrt 2-1\bigr)}.$$